# How to color the grid map based on the meter unit

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

Now I have two graph, one is a trajectory plot with unit of meter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNb1q.png)
And another is a grid map with unit of pixel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G3lY.png)

Now I want to combine them together. Since I have the grid side length, maximum, and minimum boundary of the map, I can transfer the grid map to meter unit. But I don't know how to plot the corresponding to the plot in unit of meter. I already searched on the internet, but most tutorial all teach about using the existed color map like 'red', 'white'. In my case, the color I want is my own RGB color in the form of [R, G, B].

In my previous work, I always use the code below:

```
def plotLidarOccGridMap(gridMap, xMin, yMin, gridSize):
    # Input:
    #     gridMap - The resulting occupancy grid map with shape (h, w)
    #     xMin - The minimum x coordinate of the map
    #     yMin - The minimum y coordinate of the map
    #     gridSize - The side length of each grid in the grid map
    for row in range(gridMap.shape[0]):
        for col in range(gridMap.shape[1]):
            x_grid = xMin + col * gridSize
            y_grid = yMin + (gridMap.shape[0]-row-1) * gridSize
            if gridMap[row, col] > thresOcc:
                c = 'gray'
            elif gridMap[row, col] < thresFree:
                c = 'white'
            else:
                c = 'black'
            plt.fill_between([x_grid, x_grid+gridSize], y_grid, y_grid+gridSize, color=c, edgecolor="black")
```

which work perfectly because I can use the existed color. However, now I need to plot the grid with my own customed RGB color. Can I also apply this to the function of plt.fill_between?